# JSON Deserlize getting null value for the Password Variable in apex class

Tags: json, wrapper-class

In Apex class I'm getting Null value for the Password variable. Please Guide

Apex Class

```
global with sharing class CustomerRegisterCtrl {


 @remoteAction
 global static String saveCustomerInfo(String customerJson){
 system.debug('@@@@'+customerJson);
ContactWrapper customerRec =  (ContactWrapper)JSON.deserialize(customerJson, ContactWrapper.class);
//system.assert(false,customerRec );
  system.debug('@@@@'+customerRec.Password); // This get Null Value
  if(customerRec.Subscribe==Null)customerRec.Subscribe=false;
    Contact cntctRec =  new Contact( FirstName = customerRec.FirstName, 
                                    lastName  =  customerRec.LastName,
                                    Email =  customerRec.Email,
                                    Phone = customerRec.Phone,
                                    Password__c = customerRec.Password,
                                    Subscribe_Newsletter__c = customerRec.Subscribe,
                                    MobilePhone = customerRec.mobile            
                                   //Birthdate = date.parse(customerRec.DateOfBirth)
                                    );
    insert cntctRec;

    if(cntctRec.Id != null){
        String CustomerID = SOQLUtil.getCustomerId(customerRec.Email);
        return CustomerID;
    }
    return '';

}

}
```

Wrapper Class

```
public with sharing class ContactWrapper {

public String FirstName;
public String LastName;
public String Email;
public String DateOfBirth;
public String Phone;
public String Password;
public String ConfirmPassword;
public String CustomerID;
public Boolean Subscribe;
public String mobile;

public ContactWrapper(Contact contactRec){
    this.FirstName = contactRec.FirstName;
    this.LastName =  contactRec.LastName; 
    this.Email = contactRec.Email;
    this.Phone = contactRec.Phone;
    this.Password = contactRec.Password__c;
    this.Subscribe = contactRec.Subscribe_Newsletter__c;
    this.CustomerID =  contactRec.Customer_Id__c;

}
```

}

Comment: check that password in wrapper class is value assign or not then in Remote Method Before Use password Check JSON String in that check password value.. In short Go Step By Step

Comment: @SwapnilUdamale I've assgn value. you can check in my wrapper class. when i deserialize it gets null value

Comment: From where you are calling this method `saveCustomerInfo` share that code.

Comment: @tusharsharma  'savecustomerinfo' function is calling from VF page via angular JS and all data from Vf page it getting at "system.debug('@@@@'+customerJson);" line No. 4 of apex class. My code is too long

Comment: @Amol so in line 4 did you get any value for password? Else you need to check inputs.

Comment: @TusharSharma yes in line 4 Gets the correct password value as required from VF page .

Comment: Tried to check if case - sensitivity would cause this issue, bt looks like it does not matter. Though spelling from the json structure could result in this type of null values. For example : http://i67.tinypic.com/24q7mom.jpg , the first debug works fine and second does not work as there is space beside the password attribute in the json, do check for these things and if your password attribute is json by itself ..

Comment: @Amol : Do share your json structure here, so that it adds more insight to the question

Comment: @Sumuga you are correct. due to attribute name is different it gives null value. Now Problem is solve. Thanks to all For your help